# Do multiple construction offices speed up building time?

Tags: tropico-4

In Tropico 4, does having multiple construction offices improve building time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each building generally only has a couple of slots for builders, so it is unlikely that your individual buildings will get done significantly faster.  However, having multiple construction offices means that you can work on more buildings simultaneously, so if you find yourself frequently staring at empty construction sites because your builders are busy elsewhere, it can be helpful.

Comment: It should help them get done almost twice as fast (except for travel time) if you don't mind double the costs.

Comment: I hope that's the case, I remember in tropico 3 where I would stare at two or three construction buildings with no work scheduled *sigh*

Comment: @yx_: They still won't schedule work if no one's in the building, but it's twice as likely that someone will be.

Comment: @Yx that still happens irritatingly often.

Comment: @Shadur Construction only happens when the builders are "on duty".  If they are off fulfilling one of their other needs, they won't be working.  Make it easy for them to fill those other needs, and they should get back to work faster.